# SQL I need to extract a stored procedure name from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, reverse, charindex

I am a bit new to this site but I have looked an many possible answers to my question but none of them has answered my need.  I have a feeling it's a good challenge. Here it goes.

In one of our tables we list what is used to run a report this can mean that we can have a short EXEC [svr1].[dbo].[stored_procedure] or "...From svr1.dbo.stored_procedure...".

My goal is to get the stored procedure name out of this string (column).  I have tried to get the string between '[' and ']' but that breaks when there are no brackets.  I have been at this for a few days and just can't seem to find a solution.

Any assistance you can provide is greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for entertaining this question.
almostanexpert

Comment: well, no brackets, but what character exists at the end of `svr1.dbo.stored_procedure` ?

Comment: The character that follow the bracket or no bracket is a space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the ending character of your sample sentences is space, or your sentences end without trailing ( whether space or any other character other than given samples ), and assuming you have no other dots before samples, the following would be a clean way which uses `substring()`, `len()`, `charindex()` and `replace()` together :

```
with t(str) as
(
 select '[svr1].[dbo].[stored_procedure]' union all
 select 'before svr1.dbo.stored_procedure someting more' union all
 select 'abc before svr1.dbo.stored_procedure' 
), t2(str) as
(
 select replace(replace(str,'[',''),']','') from t
), t3(str) as
(
 select substring(str,charindex('.',str)+1,len(str)) from t2 
)
select 
       substring(  
                 str,
                 charindex('.',str)+1,
                 case 
                 when charindex(' ',str) > 0 then
                      charindex(' ',str)
                 else
                           len(str)
                 end - charindex('.',str)
                ) as "Result String"  
   from t3;

Result String
----------------
stored_procedure
stored_procedure 
stored_procedure
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=90511ea1ad08abe8850793120d88b1d3)</kbd>

Comment: Hello Barbaros,
Thank you for your suggestion.  I will give it a try.  You may find this a very elementary question but nonetheless, what would go in the t cte for the Select statement?

Comment: Hi @almostanexpert .  I'm aware that I walked through multi-CTE to be able to get a clear solution. It's daunting to use string operations in SQL Server in contrast to Oracle DB :)

Answer (score 0):

With the variability of inputs you seem to have we will need to plan for a few scenarios.  The below code assumes that there will be exactly two '.' characters before the stored_procedure, and that [stored_procedure] will either end the string or be followed by a space if the string continues.

```
SELECT TRIM('[' FROM TRIM(']' FROM          --Trim brackets from final result if they exist
    SUBSTR(column || ' ',                   --substr(string, start_pos, length), Space added in case proc name is end of str
        INSTR(column || ' ', '.', 1, 2)+1,  --start_pos: find second '.' and start 1 char after
            INSTR(column || ' ', ' ', INSTR(column || ' ', '.', 1, 2), 1)-(INSTR(column || ' ', '.', 1, 2)+1)) 
                -- Len: start after 2nd '.' and go until first space (subtract 2nd '.' index to get "Length")
))FROM TABLE;
```

Working from the middle out we'll start with using the SUBSTR function and concatenating a space to the end of the original string.  This allows us to use a space to find the end of the stored_procedure even if it is the last piece of the string.

Next to find our starting position, we use INSTR to search for the second instance of the '.' and start 1 position after.

For the length argument, we find the index of the first space after that second '.' and then subtract that '.' index.

From here we have either [stored_procedure] or stored_procedure.  Running the TRIM functions for each bracket will remove them if they exist, and if not will just return the name of the procedure.

Sample inputs based on above description:

```
'EXEC [svr1].[dbo].[stored_procedure]'
'EXEC [svr1].[dbo].[stored_procedure] FROM TEST'
'svr1.dbo.stored_procedure'
```

Note: This code is written for Oracle SQL but can be translated to mySQL using similar functions.

Comment: Thank you for this solution, I am going to try it and see if it works, thx.

Comment: Also as a note from the comments above, if you are sure there will always be a space after the stored procedure name then you do not need to concatenate another one to the column.  That is a safeguard in case the string ended as '... [stored_procedure]'

Comment: I am getting tripped over by the different unsupported functions in mySQL.

Comment: T-SQL doesn't have anything close to `INSTR`. But you could easily create an INSTR function using ngrams8k.